# When using find -name in Linux what does it refer to?

Tags: linux

The man page states that find -name refers to base of file name however I don't follow what that means exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "base of the filename" is the last part of the file path: The same thing you would get if you ran the `basename`(1) command.  Typically this is everything after the last `/`.
This is as opposed to the `dirname` - the directory portion, or everything up to (but not including) the last `/`.
Together these make up the *pathname* of the file.

See [the man page for basename (and dirname)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=basename&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&format=html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks voretaq7. I had a read of basename and dirname which either output the prefix or suffix of a string. To clarify if I use -name it strips out the prefix of the string I am looking for e.g. if I were to search `find / -name 'pwd'`, the output returns /bin/pwd. what is it stripping from the string?

Comment: The behavior is to avoid something like `find /var -name foo` from returning `/var/foo`, `/var/foo/bar`, `/var/foo/baz`, etc.  By operating on the last part of the path (the basename) it avoids grabbing all the stuff under a matching directory that probably *isn't* what you're looking for.

Comment: For an equally contrived but more real-world example, `find / -name bin` will find `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` and maybe a few other spots.  If it operated on the full pathname instead of the basename you'd also get `/bin/ls`, `/bin/bash`, and everything else in those directories: A few hundred files that probably aren't what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I am being a complete noob. To clarify, if I were to run the command `find / -name 'pwd'`, it is stripping out the / directory and returning only the absolute path i.e. /bin/pwd. Is that right? I am equally confused between the use of basename and full pathname. For me a full pathname is the absolute path e.g. `/bin/pwd` and the basename is `pwd`. Is that correct?

Comment: When you say `If it operated on the full pathname instead of the basename you'd also get /bin/ls, /bin/bash, and everything else in those directories`, I take you mean that if I were to run the command as follows; `find / bin`

Comment: Not quite - your understanding of basename and pathname are basically correct, but find isn't "stripping" anything: It's looking for matches in the basename, and returning the path to the result to you.  Also note that `find` can operate on (and return) relative paths: Try `cd /etc ; find . -name passwd` to see the effect.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/899/discussion-between-voretaq7-and-peanutsmonkey)

Answer (score 2):

`-name` is the string you are searching for. eg:

```
# find /etc/ -name passwd
/etc/pam.d/passwd
/etc/passwd
```

```
# find /usr/bin -name firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

Comment: /jscott - Thanks Daniel Baker/jscott. What happens if I omit -name and simply enter the string I am looking for e.g. find /etc/ 'passwd'. How is this any different?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - `-name` is a search predicate (it tells `find` what to look for).  With no explicit predicate find treats its arguments as places to look (so `find /etc/ passwd` means "Look in */etc/* and *./passwd* and tell me what you find.)  -- Depending on which flavor of Linux you have The FreeBSD man page for `find` (with examples) may be more helpful:  http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&format=html for more info